# Keep keyboard open on focus change between text fields

Tags: ios, keyboard, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In my app developed in Appcelerator Titanium for iOS and Android, I have textfields that I would like to navigate between when the user clicks the return button.

On Android this is handled automatically by setting return key type next. For iOS I have to add event listeners that triggers a focus on the next field when the return button is clicked.

However, while the switch of focus is happening, the keyboard is animating down and then up again. Code example to show the behavior:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({width: Ti.UI.FILL,height: Ti.UI.FILL,backgroundColor:'white'});
var input1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    width: 50, height:20, top: 50, hintText: 'input1',
    returnKeyType: Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_NEXT
});
input1.addEventListener("return",function(){input2.focus();});
win.add(input1);
var input2 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    width: 50, height:20, top: 100, hintText: 'input2',
    returnKeyType: Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_NEXT
});
input2.addEventListener("return",function(){input1.focus();});
win.add(input2);
win.open();
```

According to a answer that was given before (and later removed), it is possible to keep the keyboard open in vanilla iOS. So - is there a way to use this technique to keep the keyboard open during the switching of textfield focus on iOS in Appcelerator? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent several hours on this before looking at the Titanium source for iOS (I don't really speak Obj. C).  In the end I learned that a property that I knew about behaved exactly opposite of what I expected.  All you need to do is set `suppressReturn` to `false`.

I'll also supply my portable code for forms that advance to the next field on return:

**The View**

```
<View id='signupForm' class='formContainer'>
    <TextField id='emailField' name='email' class='loginField emailField' hintText='email' onReturn='selectNextField' onFocus='scrollToField' />
    <View class="hrLine"></View>
    <TextField id='passwordField' name='password' class='loginField' hintText='password' passwordMask='true' onReturn='selectNextField' onFocus='scrollToField' />
    <View class="hrLine"></View>
    <TextField id='fnameField' class='loginField' name='fname' hintText='first name' onReturn='selectNextField' onFocus='scrollToField' autocapitalization='Ti.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_WORDS'/>
    <View class="hrLine"></View>
    <TextField id='lnameField' class='loginField' name='lname' hintText='last name' returnKeyType='Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_GO' onReturn='submitSignup' onFocus='scrollToField' autocapitalization='Ti.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_WORDS'/>
</View>
```

**The Style**

```
'.loginField': {
    height: 40,
    width: '100%',
    opacity: 1,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    returnKeyType: Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_NEXT,
    // THE CRITICAL LINE
    suppressReturn: false
}
```

**The Controller**

```
// controller.js
function selectNextField(e) {
    var hint = e.source.getHintText(),
        nextOne = false,
        finished = false;

    // find currently focused field then declare that the next field is THE ONE
    _.each($.signupForm.getChildren(), function(view) {
        if(finished) {
            return;
        }

        if(view.getHintText && view.getHintText() === hint) {
            nextOne = true;
            return;
        }
        if(nextOne && view.getApiName() === 'Ti.UI.TextField') {
            finished = true;
            return view.focus();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: One line solved the problem, love it! Sorry for the delay in marking the answer as correct, managed to miss your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use `returnKeyType :Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_NEXT` property for your TextField

Mor details [Titanium.UI.TextField](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField)

Comment: I have this property set on the textfields. On Android this is enough but not on ios where an eventlistener must be added as well, resulting in the described behaviour.

Comment: Sure! Have edited the OP and added a full code example showing the behavior on iOS. Approx 1/4 times the keyboard stays when I try this in the simulator, the other times the keyboard animates back and forth.

Comment: remove these code and run app again `input1.addEventListener("return",function(){input2.focus();});`  `input2.addEventListener("return",function(){input1.focus();});
`

Comment: When I do that, the input does not move between the fields on iOS. Keyboard closes and current field loose focus.